# How to hide an element depending on a boolean variable?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this jsp:

```
 <table>

                            <% ArrayList<Something> monAM = (ArrayList<Something>) request.getAttribute("monAM");
                               Time t = new Time();

                            for (Prescription p : monAM) {
                                boolean asd= t.lastTaken(p.getDay(), p.getDateLastTaken());

                            %>
                            <tr>

                            <input type="hidden" value="<%=asd%>" name="display"/>
                                <td >
                                    <div >
                                    <input id="nottaken"type="checkbox" name="drinkmed" value="<%=p.getPrescriptionID()%>"
                                           />
                                    <p id="taken" >Taken</p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <%}%>

                        </table>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
        var asd = document.getElementById("display").value;
       $(document).ready(function() {

            if(asd==="true"){
                document.getElementById("taken").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("nottaken").style.display="none";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("nottaken").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("taken").style.display="none";
            }

        });

    </script>
```

The java codes and the methods are working perfectly however I'm having a hard time with displaying the elements using javascript. I want to display the input #nottaken if the boolean asd is false and the

#taken when asd is true.

Comment: you can do the same onLoad body attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking value of hidden field before `document.ready` so how value of an element can be read before `document.ready`.Check value of hidden field in `document.ready`. Also you should have included Jquery file. Try this

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var asd = document.getElementById("display").value;
        if(asd==="true"){
            document.getElementById("taken").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("nottaken").style.display="none";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("nottaken").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("taken").style.display="none";
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Jquery file for using jquery funcitons. You can download from here http://jquery.com/download/ .Download latest version.

Comment: I changed the script already and added the jquery. I also corrected my mistake of not assigning an id="display" to my input. If you can notice the input asd is in a for loop so its value is changing. Apparently it worked only to the first item in the loop. I think this is because, the   document.ready() and onload event are only working once the window is open resulting for the function to work for one specifically the first item on the loop.

Comment: But i have no idea how to make the javascript function work in the loop. Pls help me I've been stuck here for two days.

Comment: What you mean by loop. At end you will have only one value in display.

Comment: since the row is in a for loop, it's printed repeatedLY until it reaches the end of the loop. On the first iteration the value of display is false thus printing the input #nottaken only. However on the succeeding iterations, both #nottaken and #taken are printing. I assume that the first iteration worked because of document.ready. Now i need to make that function work repeatedly as the value of display changes, thus printing either #taken or #nottaken for the rest of the iterations

Comment: So you cannot call javascript in loop because i have no idea of JSP.